# request in mysql send no data, except in phpmyadmin

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, request

I met some trouble while creating a podium.

In fact I would like to display the best of my employee.

SO i have done a podium

and for the first three best, I do some query like that:

for the first one:

```
$sql="SELECT `gestionnaire`.`nom`,`gestionnaire`.`prenom`,`gestionnaire`.`urlavatar`,`gestionnaire`.`civilite`, `versements`.`date_reception`, `versements`.`etat`, SUM(honoraires) as TOTAL FROM `versements` INNER JOIN `gestionnaire` ON `gestionnaire`.`id` = `versements`.`gestionnaire_id` WHERE `versements`.`id_company` ='".$societe['id']."' AND `versements`.`etat`='3' AND`date_reception` > '".date('Y-m-')."01' AND `date_reception` < '".date('Y-m-')."31' GROUP BY `versements`.`gestionnaire_id` ORDER BY `versements`.`honoraires` DESC LIMIT 0,1";
```

For the second one:

```
$sql2="SELECT `gestionnaire`.`nom`,`gestionnaire`.`prenom`,`gestionnaire`.`urlavatar`,`gestionnaire`.`civilite`, `versements`.`date_reception`, `versements`.`etat`, SUM(honoraires) as TOTAL FROM `versements` INNER JOIN `gestionnaire` ON `gestionnaire`.`id` = `versements`.`gestionnaire_id` WHERE `versements`.`id_company` ='".$societe['id']."' AND `versements`.`etat`='3' AND `date_reception` > '".date('Y-m-')."01' AND `date_reception` < '".date('Y-m-')."31' GROUP BY `versements`.`gestionnaire_id` ORDER BY `versements`.`honoraires` DESC LIMIT 1,2";
```

And for the third:

```
$sql3="SELECT `gestionnaire`.`nom`,`gestionnaire`.`prenom`,`gestionnaire`.`urlavatar`,`gestionnaire`.`civilite`, `versements`.`date_reception`, `versements`.`etat`, SUM(honoraires) as TOTAL FROM `versements` INNER JOIN `gestionnaire` ON `gestionnaire`.`id` = `versements`.`gestionnaire_id` WHERE `versements`.`id_company` ='".$societe['id']."' AND `versements`.`etat`='3' AND `date_reception` > '".date('Y-m-d',strtotime($_POST['date_debut']))."' AND `date_reception` < '".date('Y-m-d',strtotime($_POST['date_fin']))."' GROUP BY `versements`.`gestionnaire_id` ORDER BY `versements`.`honoraires` DESC LIMIT 2,3";
```

For the three best I have no trouble.

But when I try to display the rest, from the 4th to the end, I met some trouble, Actualy I've done a query that I limit 4,100 to display the rest.

So the query is like that:

```
$rqt="SELECT `gestionnaire`.`nom`,`gestionnaire`.`prenom`,`gestionnaire`.`urlavatar`,`gestionnaire`.`civilite`, `versements`.`date_reception`, `versements`.`etat`, SUM(honoraires) as TOTAL FROM `versements` INNER JOIN `gestionnaire` ON `gestionnaire`.`id` = `versements`.`gestionnaire_id` WHERE `versements`.`id_company` ='".$societe['id']."' AND `versements`.`etat`='3' AND `date_reception` > '".date('Y-m-d',strtotime($_POST['date_debut']))."' AND `date_reception` < '".date('Y-m-d',strtotime($_POST['date_fin']))."' GROUP BY `versements`.`gestionnaire_id` ORDER BY `versements`.`honoraires` DESC LIMIT 3,100";
```

when I copy and paste the echo of the query in phpmyadmin it works fine, it display to me the good results.

But when I try to echo the result, I have nothing.

I've done a loop that echo the results like that:

```
<p align="left"><?php
if(!isset($_POST['date_debut'])) { $rqt="SELECT `gestionnaire`.`nom`,`gestionnaire`.`prenom`,`gestionnaire`.`urlavatar`,`gestionnaire`.`civilite`, `versements`.`date_reception`, `versements`.`etat`, SUM(honoraires) as TOTAL FROM `versements` INNER JOIN `gestionnaire` ON `gestionnaire`.`id` = `versements`.`gestionnaire_id` WHERE `versements`.`id_company` ='".$societe['id']."' AND `versements`.`etat`='3' AND `date_reception` > '".date('Y-m-')."01' AND `date_reception` < '".date('Y-m-')."31' GROUP BY `versements`.`gestionnaire_id` ORDER BY `versements`.`honoraires` DESC ";
}
else
{
    $rqt="SELECT `gestionnaire`.`nom`,`gestionnaire`.`prenom`,`gestionnaire`.`urlavatar`,`gestionnaire`.`civilite`, `versements`.`date_reception`, `versements`.`etat`, SUM(honoraires) as TOTAL FROM `versements` INNER JOIN `gestionnaire` ON `gestionnaire`.`id` = `versements`.`gestionnaire_id` WHERE `versements`.`id_company` ='".$societe['id']."' AND `versements`.`etat`='3' AND `date_reception` > '".date('Y-m-d',strtotime($_POST['date_debut']))."' AND `date_reception` < '".date('Y-m-d',strtotime($_POST['date_fin']))."' GROUP BY `versements`.`gestionnaire_id` ORDER BY `versements`.`honoraires` DESC LIMIT 3,100";
}

$res=mysql_query($rqt);
$i5=3;
while($donnees=mysql_fetch_assoc($res));
{
echo $rqt;  
?>
Position <?php echo ++$i5 ; var_dump($donnees); ?>: <?php echo $donnees['civilite'].' '.$donnees['nom'].' '.$donnees['prenom'] ; ?> Total d'honoraires: <?php  echo number_format($donnees['TOTAL'], 2, ',', ' ');?> &euro;<br /><?php }?></p>
```

The display of the result display nothing when I do a var_dump it says bolean false.

I'm realy lost, I do not understand why in phpmyadmibn the request send to me some results, and there in my page I have this kind of mistake.

Anykind of help will be much appreciated.

Kind regards.

SP.

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL injections. Also don't use the old and deprecated `mysql_` functions.

Comment: Just a correction in queries, for second and third record you are using limit 1,2 and 2,3 which is incorrect. If you want only one record then second parameter of limit should be 1 so it should be 1,1 and 2,1. Syntax of Limit is (offset, row_count)

Comment: Ok thanks for the reply, I've modify it But for the last query I'm realy lost, I do not understand why I have no result, and in phpmyadmin I have full results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the semicolon after the while loop, it should work.
You have terminated while loop by semicolon.

Comment: Thank you so much I've been looking for that since 2 hours... Thank you so much. Receive my Utmost Respect